# How to check a text exist on page using Selenium::Remote::Driver

Tags: perl, selenium-webdriver, perl-module

I have to check whether a particular text exists on a page using Selenium::Remote::Driver.

I want to enter a particular text in the search and check whether this text exists on the page

type a text in seach-box

```
my $such_inhalt = "fuer";
my $such=$driver->find_element("term","name");
$such->send_keys($such_inhalt);
```

search

```
$driver->find_element('//*[@id="searchsubmit"]')->click;
```

Result:
check if the text found from search or not

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? SO isn't here to just write code for you. You are expected to have made some effort before posting here.

Comment: more details? enough?

Comment: You've tried to answer my first question, but you've ignored my second one. You already have an answer - does that not work for you?

Comment: check if serch found the text or not

Answer (score 1):

You can use get_page_source method to get page source (HTML) and then use Regex (or a Parser) to look for desired string/pattern.

```
use Selenium::Remote::Driver;
my $driver = Selenium::Remote::Driver->new;
$driver->get('http://www.perl.org');
my $search = 'find_this_term';
print "$search exists in page" if $driver->get_page_source() =~ /$search/;
```

---

If you are searching for the text at an **exact** location then you can do something like below:

```
$text = $driver->get_text("//div[\@name='q']");
print "Found text" if ($text eq 'find_this_term');
```